# Reviewing Suggested Edits when question should be flagged

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits, I saw a question that I would have considered NARQ. The edit made to it made sense, mostly grammar and "politeness" we changed, but the question was still NARQ. Do I approve the edit since it makes the question better (readability, not answer-ability), or do I reject because the entire question should die a slow painful death?

Edit in question: https://superuser.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/12253

Comment: Review is out of beta, [this link works](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/12253)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do I reject because the entire question should die a slow painful death?

That wouldn't be the reason to reject. I mean, we don't want the question to "die" or however you may call it — we just don't want to bump a question unnecessarily.

Actually, we *do* want to give questions a second chance. If the edit had been a **substantial** improvement that would have given others a reason to consider removing their downvote, or even possibly voting to reopen, then you should have accepted it. It would have given the question another chance.

But if the edit is just rearranging the words a little, leaving everyone as confused as before, by all means, reject it.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the misspelling :P

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, slhck rejected it explaining it.