# Suggested Edit - Reject Reason

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, reject

As per [this meta discussion](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5374/reviewing-suggested-edits-when-question-should-be-flagged?cb=1) I asked about, I had to reject more because the edits still don't make the question on topic. Since this is the most popular reason that I am rejecting edits, can we change the canned responses to maybe include something along the lines of that, to let suggested editors know? For example

`This edit does not make the question more on topic or acceptable on Superuser. Please read the FAQ to see what type of questions should be on here, and make sure your edits would make the question acceptable`

Or something to that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because I don't believe that should be a reason to reject an edit.

I often see questions that are a **pain to read**. After I read them, I feel like someone owes me the minutes of my life back.

But I **have to read** them, otherwise I can't judge if they're on-topic.

So, if someone takes the time to make the question *less* of a pain to read for everyone... **Thanks!**